# I want to use jmrtd android client

Tags: android, open-source, nfc

I followed the direction of this page 
http://sourceforge.net/p/jmrtd/code/1490/tree/trunk/androidclient/
and when I executed the last command ant -f build_jar_deps.xml 
I faced the following error,

[exec] svn: E170000: URL 'https://scuba.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/scuba/s
cuba_sc_indep' doesn't exist

I visited the above link and I see page not found error 
What is the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right forum for build errors for specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late with reply, but if anybody is still interested in JMRTD Android app, I have developed a new project from scratch:

https://github.com/tananaev/passport-reader

It's a standard Gradle project, so it's very easy to build from command line or Android Studio. All third party libraries, including JMRTD, are downloaded automatically from Maven.

Comment: Hello Anton! I am trying to read MRTD from IDCard via Card Reader, connected to Android device. I've been able to read MRZ from DG1. Now I stalled at reading image from DG2. Does your example suit for working with CardReader. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure. I have only tried it with embedded Android NFC chip and a passport.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the jarjar1.3.jar and change the path.